# SVG and dark mode not working as expected in chromium based browsers

Tags: css, svg, firefox, chromium, darkmode

I'm trying to change the `stop-color` in a svg when in dark mode. This is what I did:

```css
  stop[offset="10%"] {
    stop-color: var(--stop-10);
  }
  stop[offset="95%"] {
    stop-color: var(--stop-95);
  }

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  :root {
    --stop-10: red;
    --stop-95: gold;
  }
}
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root {
    --stop-10: pink;
    --stop-95: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="myGradient">
      <stop offset="10%"  />
      <stop offset="95%"  />
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>
 
  <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="4" fill="url('#myGradient')" />
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

It works as expected in Firefox and Safari. But it doesn't in Chromium based browsers. The colors do not change when I enable darkmode.

Is this a bug in chromium ? Any way around it?

Comment: Does it work as expected in Chrome?

Comment: @Asesh No. Same for all chromium based browsers. Need to refresh the page to see the darkmode only colors, whereas in firefox and safari it changes immediately

Comment: I think it was a bug in some Chrome versions...